# How to insert checkbox value into DB in Laravel?

Tags: html, database, laravel-8

I'm trying to insert the checkbox value into the database in the Laravel framework but can't. I keep on getting the following error.

> Attempt to assign property 'record_id3' of non-object

**Controller**

```php
public function Postindex1(Request $request)
{
    $pd4 = new Questioncourse();
    $pd4 = $request->all();

    $pd5 = implode(',', $request->input('hobby'));
    $pd5 = implode(',', $request->input('interest'));
    $pd5 = implode(',', $request->input('career'));

    $pd4['hobby'] = $pd5;
    $pd4['interest'] = $pd5;
    $pd4['career'] = $pd5;
    $pd4->record_id3 = Auth::user()->id;
    $pd4->save();

    return redirect('/question')->with('success', 
        'Your preferences have been saved!');
}
```

**Migration**

```php
Schema::create('questioncourses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('record_id3')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('record_id3')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->string('hobby');
    $table->string('interest');
    $table->string('career');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Is $pd4['record_id3'] = Auth::user()->id; working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors on your code :

```
$pd4 = new Questioncourse(); // Here you instanciate the Questioncourse Model
$pd4 = $request->all(); // Here you discard the value of $pd4 and change it with an Array 
                        // containing the $request data
```

So you don't have an instance of `Questioncourse` anymore, and therefore, you can't use the calss's methods nor attributes (like `record_id3`).

**What you have to do :**

1. You don't need `$pd4 = $request->all();`, remove it,
2. Use a different variable for each checkbox group (not just `$pd5`!),
3. Use the [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to set the values af the Model's attributes, so your final code should be like this :

   ```
   public function Postindex1(Request $request){
       $pd4 = new Questioncourse();
       // $pd4 = $request->all(); There is no need for this

       $hobby = implode(',', $request->input('hobby'));
       $interest = implode(',', $request->input('interest'));
       $career = implode(',', $request->input('career'));

       $pd4->hobby = $hobby;
       $pd4->interest = $interest;
       $pd4->career = $career;
       $pd4->record_id3 = Auth::user()->id;

       $pd4->save();

       return redirect('/question')->with('success', 'Your preferences have been saved!'); 
   }
   ```